# Java EE "JDI Event Dispatch" error

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to debug any project in Java EE INDIGO (64 bit) in win 7 and place a breakpoint somewhere the program acts as expected but when I hit f6 or f5 to go further eclipse throws an error which reads (I have Spring installed):

```
An internal error occurred during: "JDI Event Dispatch".
com.springsource.sts.groovy.debug.core.GroovyDebugProvider.isAlwaysInteretingLaunch()Z
```

(No typo, "Z" does appear)
Now I can't debug any program because it always gives this error. Can anyone help?

From the eclipse error log:

```
!MESSAGE com.springsource.sts.groovy.debug.core.GroovyDebugProvider.isAlwaysInteretingLaunch()Z
!STACK 0
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.springsource.sts.groovy.debug.core.GroovyDebugProvider.isAlwaysInteretingLaunch()Z
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.debug.DebugHooksAspect.isInterestingLaunch(DebugHooksAspect.aj:253)
    at org.eclipse.contribution.jdt.debug.DebugHooksAspect.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$org_eclipse_contribution_jdt_debug_DebugHooksAspect$org_eclipse_contribution_jdt_debug_DebugHooksAspect$isInterestingLaunch(DebugHooksAspect.aj:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.getStepFilters_aroundBody1$advice(JDIDebugTarget.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIDebugTarget.getStepFilters(JDIDebugTarget.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.attachFiltersToStepRequest(JDIThread.java:2154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.createStepRequest(JDIThread.java:2065)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.createStepRequest(JDIThread.java:2040)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$StepHandler.step(JDIThread.java:1989)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread.stepOver(JDIThread.java:1412)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIStackFrame.stepOver(JDIStackFrame.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.commands.StepOverCommand.step(StepOverCommand.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.commands.StepCommand.doExecute(StepCommand.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.commands.AbstractDebugCommand$1.run(AbstractDebugCommand.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Appears for Eclipse Juno/Indigo with Android Debugging as well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a similar bug to this [bug in codehaus jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1208?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs) (see comments section). I was able to switch back to an older eclipse installation (from two weeks ago) to get rid of the current problem and will upgrade to Eclipse 3.7 as soon as time permits.

Answer (score 0):

As crazy as this sounds, I too was getting this error when debugging an Android App and trying to step into a specific method, and resolved it by renaming the method I was trying to step into.

I had tried:

- completely reinstalling the app
- cleaning in Eclipse
- reboot of device (phone), OS, and restart of Eclipse
- increasing debug timeouts in Preferences | Java | Debug

My method was called "getMessageInfoFromDb"... and was in a class that didn't extend anything, but implemented Serializable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling simple step filtering, especially filtering of simple getters.

Answer (score 0):

delete the Temp folder from yourlocalpath\domainfolder\server\AdminServer

domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer

Comment: You can give more explantion

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any DB import twice or more time on the same DB that you use for the application in which you are running in debug mode. Because I am also getting similar error with the caption `JDI` while starting Application Server with deployed `.ear` in Eclipse based IDE as a popup.

When db is imported twice user created tables gets imported if it's been tried in the same kind of databases. But Oracle App & System Specific tables throws error in process of importing. And some crash in that....

I hope this is what scenario yours as well....

In my scenario I had imported Oracle db from UNIX environment to Oracle XE in Windows environment.